# Queries regarding SonarQube 6.7 (LTS)

Tags: sonarqube

I have few queries regarding SonarQube 6.7 (LTS)

1)  If I start the sonarqube service with root account from Ubuntu machine, it fails with below error.

**Error message**

From SONARQUBE_HOME/logs/es.log it was showing error as below:

```
2017.11.09 08:42:29 ERROR es[][o.e.b.Bootstrap] Exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:106) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
```

However, with a non-root account I was able to start the service and it is working fine now. So is there any way available to use root account to start the service? If so let me know the same.

2)  Dashboard and Configure Widgets options not showing in this version, Are these options removed from this version? Please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot run SonarQube as root. It was never a good idea to do that - now SonarQube will not even start.

The dashboard has been replaced by new and more powerful project pages.